# How can I stop indexing under Synology DSM 7.0 permanently?

Tags: nas, synology-diskstation

I recently upgraded to version 7.0 and the previously working permanent disable process as in https://mariushosting.com/how-to-disable-or-uninstall-synology-universal-search/
does not work anymore because the command synoservicecfg doesn't exist anymore.
In "Universal Search" -> "Indexed Folder" -> "Synology Drive" there is an entry for my backup folder but it cannot be deleted or modifed (only the arbitrary name can be modified). Indexing takes too much time and is not needed.

Any ideas how to disable?

Please note that after shutdown and boot again, the setting "stop indexing permanently" has gone.

Note: with version7.0 there is no synoservice command anymore

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/synology/comments/hbbz8v/comment/fv978il/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 If that works, please write your own answer and accept it.

Comment: The above method posted in reddit a year ago doesn't work anymore in DSM 7.0 as the synoservice command doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Maybe just ask Synology support and then post the answer here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution is proposed in the bug-report
[Does not work on DSM 7 #3](https://github.com/alexanderharm/syno-webdav-keeweb/issues/3):

> In DSM 7 `synoservice` has been replaced by `systemctl`.
>
> Therefore it is necessary to modify the line 111 in
> `syno-webdav-keeweb/synoWebdavKeeweb.sh`:
>
> ```
> synoservice --restart pkgctl-WebDAVServer
> ```
>
> by:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl restart pkgctl-WebDAVServer
> ```

In that spirit, the command to disable `SynoFinder` is:

```
sudo systemctl disable pkgctl-SynoFinder
```

(I cannot test since I don't have Synology.)

Answer (score 3):

I made a Scheduled Task. Open Control Panel, Task Scheduler, choose Create -> Trigered Task -> User defined script.

In General tab:

- Task name `disable indexing`
- Choose User `root`
- Event: `Boot-up`.

In Task Settings tab, Run command, user-defined script put:

```
/usr/syno/bin/synopkg stop SynoFinder
```

Comment: task-log/disable indexing/1643388281/script.log: line 1: synoservice: command not found

Comment: sorry, that was old dsm6.2 command, updated for new DSM7

Comment: In DSM 7 this also disables Drive Server. Be careful!

Answer (score 2):

The correct ssh commands for DSM7 is

```
sudo systemctl stop pkg-SynoFinder-fileindexd.service
sudo systemctl disable pkg-SynoFinder-fileindexd.service
```

For this you need to have ssh access. You may can achieve the same if you run this command only once as a scheduled task with root privileges through the web UI.

As mentioned above to disable the `pkgctl-SynoFinder` will also stop the "Synology Drive Service" which may not what you want.

But if you disable `pkg-SynoFinder-fileindexd` the "Synology Drive Service" still seems to work properly

Comment: Regarding the same subjet, can you please have a look a my question [here](https://superuser.com/q/1792293/528454) ?