# Can I safely stop and disable the "pkgctl-SynoFinder" service on DSM7?

Tags: nas, services, search-indexing, synology-diskstation

Index files are still created on my Synology DSM7 although the `pkg-SynoFinder-fileindexd` service is disabled and not running :

```shell
$ systemctl status pkg-SynoFinder-fileindexd
● pkg-SynoFinder-fileindexd.service - pkg-SynoFinder-fileindexd
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/pkg-SynoFinder-fileindexd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
$
```

There is also a `synoindexd` service which is not running :

```shell
$ systemctl status synoindexd
● synoindexd.service - synoindexd
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/synoindexd.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
$
```

However, there is a `pkgctl-SynoFinder` service running :

```shell
$ systemctl status pkgctl-SynoFinder
● pkgctl-SynoFinder.service - SynoFinder's service unit
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/pkgctl-SynoFinder.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Thu 2022-08-25 13:04:10 CEST; 10 months 2 days ago
 Main PID: 23098 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /SynoFinder.slice/pkgctl-SynoFinder.service
```

This solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/1789399/528454) says the `pkgctl-SynoFinder` service is needed by the `Synology Drive Service` but I see NO dependency here :

```shell
$ systemctl cat pkgctl-SynoFinder | egrep -i "drive|indexd"
$ systemctl -a | grep -i drive
  syno-notify-bundle-drive-update.service                                                                              loaded    active     exited       Notify bundle drive update after bootup done
  syno-notify-idle-drive.service                                                                                       loaded    active     exited       Notify all idle drives after bootup done
  syno-notify-unsupport-drive.service                                                                                  loaded    active     exited       Notify system is detected for unsupported drive
$
```

Therefore, can I safely stop and disable the `pkgctl-SynoFinder` service ?